# Symfony & AWS BS - Env vars for console outside .env files

Tags: amazon-web-services, symfony, environment-variables, symfony4, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a symfony API which runs on AWS beanstalk instances. My .env file registers the environment variables that I need in my app. I override all of them in the AWS console to adapt to my environments.

For exemple :

- Env file : **DEFAULT_CONNECTION_DSN**=bolt://user:password@host:port
- Test server : **DEFAULT_CONNECTION_DSN**=bolt://test:azerty@test.toto.com:7687
- Prod server : **DEFAULT_CONNECTION_DSN**=bolt://prod:azerty@toto.com:7687

This works because AWS overrides the environment variables when the PHP server is started, so the values placed in the .env file are ignored.

The problem is that I try to create a CRON on the server. The CRON is executed from command line, and I saw that, in this case, the variables still have the value specified in the .env file at runtime.

If I list the environment variables on the server, I see that **DEFAULT_CONNECTION_DSN** has the value that I want, but if I dump the value in my code (or execute `php bin/console debug:container --env-vars`), **DEFAULT_CONNECTION_DSN** has the .env file value. I already tried to delete the entry from my .env file. In this case, I have an error saying my environment variable is not found.

I must precise that I work with a .env.local locally, file which is not versionned, and the deploys are based on git versionning, so it seems difficult to add a .env.*env-name* file for each environement.

What could I do ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know andything about AWS beanstalk - but is it possible to push the `.env.local` file manully once?

Comment: Sadly, no. AWS beanstalk creates a new folder each time you deploy a new version. The folder content is created from the git data and the project's config online. The environment variables are specified in this config and exists on the server, the problem is that Symfony totally ignores these values... :(

Comment: Is there a option for shared directories? I am using deployer for my project, which also creates a new directory from git every time I deploy. Yet I have a shared directory for all releases where my `.env` file is included

Comment: If your problem is not directly related to Symfony, you may solve it using the answer given by @Xavi Montero in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony loads env vars **only** if they are not already present. Your problem looks like more how to add env vars with cron in AWS. As I don't know BS I can't help you with this.

In your cron I think you can still run `DEFAULT_CONNECTION_DSN=bolt://prod:azerty@toto.com:7687 php bin/console ...`, this will set your env var at runtime.

Comment: I saw this point on the documentation but I don't understand why, in this case, the server does not seems to know there already was a value.

`printenv | grep "DEFAULT_CONNECTION_DSN"` displays the correct value.
But when I execute my cron command, the old value is used.

Comment: And I can't set the value in my CRON because the script that creates the CRON is versionned (as it could be deployed on multiple instances of multiple environments), but the environements variables should not be versioned as they differ for each environment.

Comment: Agree with versioning, but there should be a way to add env vars at cron. This is an aws problem, not symfony related. 
Maybe you can add your env vars in your aws admin console.

Answer (score 0):

When you run something, from a bash, it inherits the exported variables, plus the ones given in the same command line.

Suppose this case:

```
xavi@bromo:~$ export -p
declare -x HOME="/home/xavi"
declare -x TERM="linux"
declare -x USER="xavi"
xavi@bromo:~$
```

Say you echo something not defined: You don't get anything, as expected:

```
xavi@bromo:~$ echo $ABC $XYZ

xavi@bromo:~$
```

You can place this echo inside a bash script, for example:

```
xavi@bromo:~$ cat /tmp/test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $ABC $XYZ
```

Then give it execution permissions:

```
xavi@bromo:~$ chmod a+x /tmp/test.sh
xavi@bromo:~$
```

Now, if you execute the script it also says nothing, but if you prefix them with variable assignment the value lives "exclussively" inside that call. See examples with hello-bye and orange-banana. If you later just show the values, they are not there:

```
xavi@bromo:~$ /tmp/test.sh

xavi@bromo:~$ ABC=hello XYZ=bye /tmp/test.sh
hello bye
xavi@bromo:~$ ABC=orange XYZ=banana /tmp/test.sh
orange banana
xavi@bromo:~$ echo $ABC $XYZ

xavi@bromo:~$
```

This would be a good approach for the solution of Fabien Papet: To prefix the cron call with the variable assignment.

But if you cannot do that, you can go furthter:

Env vars are not inherited when not exported but inherited when exported: See this:

```
xavi@bromo:~$ ABC=pita
xavi@bromo:~$ XYZ=pota
xavi@bromo:~$ /tmp/test.sh

xavi@bromo:~$ export ABC=pita
xavi@bromo:~$ export XYZ=pota
xavi@bromo:~$ /tmp/test.sh
pita pota
```

You could take advantage of bash dot-import command `.` to import variables.

Place in these files those contents:

```
xavi@bromo:~$ cat /tmp/fruits
export ABC=orange
export XYZ=tangerine
xavi@bromo:~$ cat /tmp/places
export ABC=Paris
export XYZ=Barcelona
xavi@bromo:~$
```

Note that the previous files do not have a she-bang as they are not meant to be executed, they do not have to create a bash instance. They are meant for inclussion from an existing bash instance.

Now edit the test.sh to make an inclusion of a file which we'll pass via the first command line parameter:

```
xavi@bromo:~$ cat /tmp/test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

. $1

echo $ABC $XYZ
xavi@bromo:~$
```

You can now play with the invocation. I still have the pita-pota pair from the last test. See what happens:

```
xavi@bromo:~$ echo $ABC $XYZ
pita pota
xavi@bromo:~$ /tmp/test.sh /tmp/fruits
orange tangerine
xavi@bromo:~$ /tmp/test.sh /tmp/places
Paris Barcelona
xavi@bromo:~$ echo $ABC $XYZ
pita pota
xavi@bromo:~$
```

The first line `echo $ABC $XYZ` displays our current environment.

The second line invokes a new bash (via the she-bang of `/tmp/test.sh`) and as pita-pota were exported they are momentarily there. But as soon as `. $1` is executed, it is expanded into `. /tmp/fruits` which overrides the environment by exporting new variables, thus the result.

The second scripts (the one with fruits) ends, so the bash is terminated and its environment is destroyed. We return to our main bash. In here we still have pota-pita. If we had printed now, we'd see the pita-pota. We go with the places, now.

The reasoning with the places is identical to the reasoning with the fruits.

As soon as we return to the main bash, the child env is destroyed, so the places have been blown away and we return to the first initial environment with pita-pota, which is then printed.

## So...

With all this you can:

1. Setup a bash script that wraps:

   1. loading the environment from some
      place.
   2. Call the `php bin/console`
2. In the cron, do not invoke the php but your wrapper script.

This allows you to

1. Change the script with different environments without depending on versioning.
2. Keep your credentials and configuration separated from the code.

In conclusion:

- Make your **source version control** system to have the cron versioned, and the wrapper bash script versioned.
- Make your **deployer** to place a different "includable" parameters file in each environment.
- Make your **cron** to call the wrapper.
- Make your **wrapper** to setup the env vars and call the `php bin/console`.

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helps me to better understand the environement variables comportement at a shell level, but actually, it doesn't really solve my problem. My problem is more symfony related, because my environment variables are correctly defined at the system level. My problem is that Symfony (that uses environment variables preprocessors) ignores their value and only take in account the values defined in the .env project's file.

Comment: try to run env into your cron, and you'll see that your var isn't there

Comment: To allow us help well, please take your time to improve your question by placing the relevant config and parameter files "as is" (except for subtituting the passwords by `xxxxxxx`), the code of the controller or service you are using to consume that parameter, and showing us what parameter is exactly not properly decoded. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - In particular the section "Help others reproduce the problem"